# Java 1.7 com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID data

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have done some xml signing in Java 1.6 but when I run the same example in Java 1.7 I get this kind of exception:

```
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException:
 javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException:
 com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException:
 Cannot resolve element with ID data
```

my xml:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fu="http://www.fu.gov.si/" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <fu:BusinessPremiseRequest Id="data">
            <fu:Header>
                <fu:MessageID>24A4BACB-2355-0564-E053-AB02010AD740</fu:MessageID>
                <fu:DateTime>2015-11-16T09:22:58</fu:DateTime>
            </fu:Header>
        </fu:BusinessPremiseRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is my source code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = (Document) dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));


NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("fu:BusinessPremiseRequest");
Node node = nl.item(0);

KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
p12.load(new FileInputStream("c:/cert/testfurs.p12"), "Geslo123#".toCharArray());
Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
System.out.println("Alias certifikata:" + alias);
Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, "Geslo123#".toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry
        = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("Geslo123#".toCharArray()));

X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

final XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
// Create a Reference to the enveloped document
Reference ref = sigFactory.newReference("#data",
        sigFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
        Collections.singletonList(sigFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
        null,
        null);


SignedInfo si = sigFactory.newSignedInfo(sigFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), sigFactory.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

// Create a KeyValue containing the RSA PublicKey 
KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = sigFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = keyInfoFactory.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());

List x509Content = new ArrayList();

x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
x509Content.add(x509IssuerSerial);

KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(publicKey);
X509Data xd = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);

// Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

// Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
// location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(
        privateKey,
        node
);
```

Answer (score 4):

try like this (source: https://slo-tech.com/forum/t652679/449):

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = (Document) dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(vhodniXml.getBytes()));
    //Node node = doc.getElementsByTagName("fu:BusinessPremiseRequest").item(0);
    Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
    String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Alias certifikata:" + alias);
    Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, geslo.toCharArray());

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry
            = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(geslo.toCharArray()));

    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    final XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    // Create a Reference to the enveloped document
    Reference ref = sigFactory.newReference("#data",
            sigFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
            Collections.singletonList(sigFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null,
            null);

    SignedInfo si = sigFactory.newSignedInfo(sigFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), sigFactory.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

    // Create a KeyValue containing the RSA PublicKey
    KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = sigFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
    X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = keyInfoFactory.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());

    List x509Content = new ArrayList();

    x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    x509Content.add(x509IssuerSerial);

    KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(publicKey);
    X509Data xd = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);

    // Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
    KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("fu:BusinessPremiseRequest");
    Node node = nl.item(0);

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
    // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(
            privateKey,
            node
    );
    ((Element) node).setIdAttribute("Id", true);


    // Create the XMLSignature (but don't sign it yet)
    XMLSignature signature = sigFactory.newXMLSignature(si, keyInfo);

    // Marshal, generate (and sign) the enveloped signature
    signature.sign(dsc);
```